# Share Image on Facebook with my webapp

Tags: java, javascript, html, ajax, facebook

I wrote this code to show galley on jsp

```
<c:forEach var="gallery" items="${galleria}">
<div class="uk-overlay uk-margin-top uk-margin-left uk-margin-right uk-margin-bottom">
        <a href="data:image/jpeg;base64,${gallery.value}" data-lightbox="roadtrip">
                <img  id="my_image2" src="data:image/image/jpeg;base64,${gallery.value}" width="300" height="250" alt=""></img>
        </a>
        <div class="uk-overlay-caption">
            <button class="uk-icon-button uk-icon-facebook" type="submit" value="my_image" onclick="fbs_click('my_image2')"/>
            <button class="uk-icon-button uk-icon-trash-o" type="submit" value="my_image" onclick="cancella()"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

the image that is showed is encoded from base64 to jpeg.
I want to share the image on Facebook and I tryed to wrote the following code

```
<script>
        function fbs_click(id) {
            var TheImg = document.getElementById(id);
            u = TheImg.src;
            console.log(TheImg);
            console.log(u);
            //t=document.title;
            t = TheImg.getAttribute('alt');
            window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='
                    + encodeURIComponent(u) + '&t=' + encodeURIComponent(t),
                    'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
            return false;
        }

    </script>
```

but it don't work because in my opinion it try to share base64 instead the image url. How can I fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Upload the image on your server than add the url of image to this. I am not sure but this will do your work probably.